# python regex match single pattern gives False but put patterns together gives True?

Tags: python, regex

Why each match token match give `False`, but combine them give `True`?

```
> print(re.match('[+]','...'))
  None
> print(re.match('[-]','...'))
  None
> print(re.match('[×]','...'))
  None
> print(re.match('[÷]','...'))
  None
> print(re.match('[+-×÷]','...'))
  <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='.'>
```

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), also please fully address the question, Also this question doesn't let users to be enthusiastic to solve the question , by the way, please also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question

Comment: also you say `False`, it is `None`, you say `True`, it is a regex object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last pattern (`[+-×÷]`) matches the `.`’s because when the `-` sign is unescaped in the character set, the pattern matches characters whose character codes are in the range of 43 to 215. And it just so happens that the `.` has a character code of 46 (`print(ord("."))` shows this). Testing this on a regex website like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) shows the details of the pattern:

[image: What the regex pattern looks like broken down]

(*Note where is shows that the `-` sign is acting as a range operator rather than a literal `-`*)

To fix this problem, simply escape the `-` like so, and the pattern will no longer match the `.`s.

```
re.match(‘[+\-×÷]’,'...')  #Note the added backslash after the +
```

Comment: you can put it at the end, and in that case it wont be interpreted as a range operator,just like when it was alone

Comment: @Onyambu great solution!